# Type is not assignable to itself after type narrowing

Tags: typescript, union-types, typeguards

Given the following code

```
type Test = string | boolean | string[] | boolean[]

function test (param: Test) {
  if (!_.isArray(param)) {
    param = [param]
  }

  return param
}
```

I recieve the following error

> (parameter) param: string | boolean
> Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)

The solution is

```
type Test = string | boolean | (string | boolean)[]
```

But I don't understand my solution

To put it into words I have a type which consists of two arbitrary types and (bad I know) arrays of those types. Through (!_.isArray) type guarding I (bad I know) mutate the parameter.

Inside the type guard my type definition is narrowed to 'string | boolean'. Typescript is telling me I can't assign the value I want to this type.

Please give me insight into understanding the error and solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that once you establish that `param` isn't an array, it's type is constrained to `string | boolean`, when you take a value of that type and put it in an array literal Typescript infers the type to be `[string | boolean]` which is different than `string[] | boolean[]`. If you instead checked for each possible type and then had the same line of code in a separate branch that would work:

```js
type Test = string | boolean | string[] | boolean[]

function test(param: Test) {
  if (typeof param === 'string') {
    param = [param];
  } else if (typeof param === 'boolean') {
    param = [param];
  }

  return param
}
```

In case it isn't clear the difference between these types is that one (`(string | boolean)[]`) can be an array containing a mix of strings and booleans, where as the other (`string[] | boolean[]`) is either an array of only strings, or an array of only boolean. Unfortunately Typescript isn't smart enough in this case to realize that the array `[param]` is inherently homogenous because it has only a single element.

Answer (score 0):

COnsider this solution:

```js
type Test = string | boolean | string[] | boolean[]

const test = (param: Test) => Array.isArray(param) ? param : [param]
```

You don't need to mutate anything. I believe you dont even need to use lodash here

Just my opinion:
For me, it is much readable without `!` negation operator in condition statement

**UPDATE**

Thanks **@Paul Wheeler** for correcting me.

Here you have my solution with narrowed types

```js
type Test = string | boolean | string[] | boolean[]

const strOrBool = (val: unknown): val is string | boolean =>
    typeof val === 'string' || typeof val === 'boolean'

function test<T extends string>(param: T): [T]
function test<T extends boolean>(param: T): [T]
function test<T extends string, U extends T[]>(param: [...U]): U
function test<T extends boolean, U extends T[]>(param: [...U]): U
function test<T extends Test>(param: T) {
    return strOrBool(param) ? [param] : param
}

const result = test(true) // [true]
const result2 = test('hello') // ["hello"]
const result3 = test(['hello']) // ["hello"]
const result4 = test([true]) // [true]
```

[Playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4qIE4EsB2BzKAPlAEYD2pANhAIbaFrBZ4DaAuvWZTdmwFC8BjUtkQN0AeXQAhchRRQAFADdqFAFxQArtgDW2UgHdsASg0q5meGJz4inKrRQA%20XlDdRQkUgDMo5lMioAOQYNkGERJ4QPn6qAcH23EH83toCwJjCHgjAADwwUBAAHsAQ2AAmVqF4Tgpg1OjUALYaMKZQzDCsvKnY6Zl0pYj5hSVllSSy3LX1jS2w7Z3dvf1ZQ3kFxaUVVYw2ADRQAKqj2xMwbDMNzRrMAHQPR6ztRz1pGWs5I1vjVom0hxOPx2sEudWu83uj2eGleKw%20gy%20mzGILgiCuc1axigAG9XO50BBgJp0HQMJIZJRwXNsQB%20DqzZrsDSMpq8AC%20-CEIiQhPgmgoSFQ6wUjE0EGxAHpJR0xRButzRHyBcAAEzyEVBAAWEAoFFIQSlMuYACIdXrSCaFcIlQgVQBmDU5BTMbW6-VBZ5QaUdM3uy3WnlQZWCgAsTsQLrlXp9zGjQA)

Btw, typescript does not play well with mutated values, it can lead to bugs

Comment: The `test` function in your example doesn't actually have the desired type signature. The desired signature is `Test -> Test` but your function has the signature `Test -> (string | boolean)[]`. You could verify this by declaring `let example: Test;` and then try assigning the result of the `test` function to it: `example = test('foo');`.